# Enable/disable a button in Phoenix 1.7 depending on state

Tags: button, elixir, phoenix-live-view

### Background

I have a button that may be disabled or not, depending on a set of conditions. I want to disable/enable the button without having to reload the page.

To achieve this I am using the following code:

**`my_app_live.ex`**

```
#provided as a sample
def disable_buttton? do
  if :rand.uniform(100) > 50 do
    "true"
  else
    "false"
  end
end
```

**`my_app.html.heex`**

```
<.button disabled={disable_button?)}>Execute Command</.button>
```

**`core_components.ex`**

```
  def button(assigns) do
    extra = assigns_to_attributes(assigns, [:disabled])

    assigns = assign(assigns, :disabled?, case Map.get(extra[:rest], :disabled) do
      "true" -> true
      _ -> false
    end)

    ~H"""
    <p><%= "INSIDE BUTTON: #{inspect(@disabled?)}" %></p>
    <button
      type={@type}
      class={if @disabled? do
      [
        "rounded-md bg-slate-400 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm",
        @class
      ]
    else
      [
        "rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm",
        "active:text-white/80",
        @class
      ]
    end}
      {@rest}
    >
      <%= render_slot(@inner_block) %>
    </button>
    """
  end
```

### Problem

For some reason, `<p><%= "INSIDE BUTTON: #{inspect(@disabled?)}" %></p>` always shows `true` and thus the button is always disabled.

In reality `disable_buttton?` may return true/false depending on which buttons are selected (if all forms have a value, then the button should be enabled), however I am unaware of any pattern to do this in Phoenix.

I am also not convinced I am using `assigns` properly.

### Questions

1. How can I enable/disable a button in Phoenix, depending on state?
2. Am I using `assigns_to_attributes` and `assign` correctly in this sample?

I read https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/Phoenix.Component.html#module-attributes but I still don't quite understand what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issues found

The main reason my code didn't work was because my `disable_button?` function was returning `"false"` instead of `false`. To be more precise:

> So, in Phoenix LV, if the value is false the attribute disabled is removed from the node, while if it is any other thing (like `"false"`), the node gets the attribute as disabled="something else", which means that because disabled is still present, irrespective of value, it is considered as a disabled button.

This differs from the behaviour in the browser, where if I add `disable="false"` the browser will not consider the node disabled.

Source: https://elixirforum.com/t/enable-disable-a-button-in-phoenix-1-7-depending-on-state/58007/6?u=fl4m3ph03n1x

Another issue is that this function also needs to return a value that depends on the state itself. In this case I am generating a random number, which is independent of state, thus the button would never update.

### Answer

So, for those who are curious, this is the code I ended up with:

**`core_components.ex`**

This is my modified button function:

```
  @doc """
  Renders a button.

  ## Examples

      <.button>Send!</.button>
      <.button phx-click="go" class="ml-2" disabled=false>Send!</.button>
  """
  attr :type, :string, default: nil
  attr :class, :string, default: nil
  attr :disabled, :boolean, default: false
  attr :rest, :global, include: ~w(form name value)

  slot :inner_block, required: true

  def button(assigns) do
    ~H"""
    <button
      type={@type}
      class={if @disabled do
      [
        "rounded-md bg-slate-400 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm",
        @class
      ]
    else
      [
        "phx-submit-loading:opacity-75 rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm",
        "hover:bg-indigo-500 active:text-white/80",
        @class
      ]
    end}
      {@rest}
      disabled={@disabled}
    >
      <%= render_slot(@inner_block) %>
    </button>
    """
  end
```

And here is how I use it:

**`my_app_live.html.heex`**

```
<.button class="min-w-full" disabled={disable_button?(@param1, @state)}>Execute Command</.button>
```

This depends on the state, because the state changes with time, which means my button's appearance will also change with time!